# how to delete a row in a text file with razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file, razor, text

Hi i am currently running a system where the user adds a category of food which is then appended to a text file in my app data all the categories are listed and there are buttons next to each one. When the user clicks on the button that food category bust be deleted from the textfile. I am using visual studious mvc along with razor.

Comment: *Razor* wouldn't be interacting with your text file, but presumably you've written back-end code (in C# perhaps?) which does.  The logic you define for how to identify what data to read/write in the file is really up to you.  What have you tried and what isn't working as expected?  As an aside, you'll likely find that using a database for structured data is much easier in the long run than using a flat text file.  But if the latter is necessary, your best bet is likely to structure the data in JSON or XML, manipulate it in objects, and always read/write the entire file from those objects.

Comment: This is a very general question. My recommendation is that you walk through a tutorial to understand how razor, back end code, and stored data works together. Here is a great tutorial from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/razor-pages-start?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio